# JS - Confusion between string and int variables

Tags: string, variables, int

Javascript is really bugging my head. At first I was using this code :

```
var val = document.getElementById("inputField").value; // User entered "2"
while (val < 5)
{
    val += 1
    alert(val);
}
```

But it would do 5+1 = 51 unless I use parseInt before entering the while loop. So that means that val is Not a Number. But however it has no problem considering val as a number upon entering the while loop, in the expression(val < 5).
Why is it so ? It looks illogical to me, unless you tell me that "that's the way it is".
Ty

Comment: I would recommend to you, using jquery ....

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious in programming world that `var x = 5` differs from `var x = "5"`
As the former undersands 5 as a number while the later understands 5 as a character or a string of one charcter

The problem here comes from 2 sources

**Number 1:** 
Is that the numeric value is obtained from the html control input that accepts literal text in its value property (even if it was of type number)

**Number 2:**
Is that "+" operator accepts both numeric and text operands. where `5 + 1` result in 6. While `"5" + "1"` result in "51". 
Also `"5"+1` results in `"51"`

So, javascript sees entered value is a valid as text and number and plus operations work with both types so, it handled it as a text as there is no other sign indicate it is a number

If you replace '+' with '*' which does not accept text as operands, you will get the expected result where `"5" * 5 = 25`

Here jS tried to apply multiplication on text as a number and it succeded 
But if the text was not parsaple as a number. say "x", then `"x" * 5` will result to `NaN`